# [18.04.2:Kernel 4.18.0-15-generic]plug in one camera will display two device /dev/video0 & video1

Tags: 18.04, kernel, video, camera

[18.04.2:Kernel 4.18.0-15-generic]plug in one camera will display two device /dev/video0 & video1, and can't access use opencv.
16.04:Kernel 4.15 work fine.